# C++20 range-v3 and the zip_with view adapter

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

With a lazy range combinator such as `ranges::view::reverse` I can either provide it with a single argument (e.g. `reverse(iota(0,3))`); or I can use it to adapt a range using `operator|` (e.g. `iota(0,3) | reverse`). This parity appears fairly regular; below are examples of nullary, unary, and binary views:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace ranges::view;
  std::cout <<        (iota(0,9) | reverse)      << ' ';
  std::cout << reverse(iota(0,9))                << '\n';

  std::cout <<        (iota(0,9) | chunk(4))     << ' ';
  std::cout <<   chunk(iota(0,9),4)              << '\n';

  std::cout <<        (iota(0,9) | replace(5,0)) << ' ';
  std::cout << replace(iota(0,9),5,0)            << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I notice though that the `ranges::view::zip_with` combinator can only be used in the second (non-adapter) form; such as `zip_with(std::plus{},iota(0,9),iota(0,9))`. Is there a technical reason why `zip_with` cannot be defined to work with `operator|`? Is there a canonical ordering to the arguments of the lazy range combinators in the ranges-v3 library?

I'm working with the latest release (v0.4.0) of the ranges-v3 library.

Comment: How would you pipe two ranges to a single `zip_view`?

Comment: You would just pipe one of them.

Answer (score 6):

It's a pretty common convention in range-v3 that `r | adapter(x)` means the same thing as `adapter(r, x)`. (Indeed there's even a programming language, Elixir, for which `r |> adapter(x)` actually evaluates as `adapter(r, x)` directly).

The problem with `zip_with` is that the usage, as you point out, is:

```
zip_with(std::plus{},iota(0,9),iota(0,9))
```

Which means the logical separation with `operator|` would be:

```
std::plus{} | zip_with(iota(0,9),iota(0,9))
```

But then, that's not a range on the left-hand side. That's some binary operator. range-v3 is all about chaining *ranges*. In every other case, it's the range that appears on the left-hand-side of `|`. So while it's not technically difficult to do, it seems like a substantively different kind of thing.

Comment: You also run into problems if your first range is also callable, because you now have `zip_with(deduced_potentially_callable, deduced_range)` on the rhs

Comment: Thanks for the input @Barry. In that case `zip_with` could just be defined to take its function argument last; i.e. `zip_with(iota(0,9),iota(0,9),std::plus{})`.

Comment: @user2023370 Yes but (a) `zip_with` takes a variadic amount of ranges, so the function kind of has to go first and (b) it's familiar from other languages that the function goes first (e.g. [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith)).

Comment: So maybe the convention should be that `r | adapter(x)` means the same thing as `adapter(x,r)`?